# AngularJS directive partially working (Plunker link included)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**In summary:** I want to apply form validation, but it doesn't work when I use a custom directive.

Here is a Plunker to show what I mean: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8kHB56RMc3V8bjQqneTT?p=preview)

See how by default, all of the required fields are red because they are invalid (empty). Perfect!

The only problem is, it only works when I hard code it like this:

```
<input class='form-control' type="text" name="userInput" ng-model="item.answer" required />
```

What I really want is to use this directive (which is commented out currently):

```
<input-field item="item"></input-field>
```

If you remove the hard-coded input and uncomment the `input-field` then you will see the script stops working. Yes, it "looks" okay but the validation is completely lost.

And I have no idea why - so any ideas would be most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this and was able to resolve it. In your example I had to change two things:

1) You need to use `ng-required="true"` and not just `ng-required` on this line:
`var required = (scope.item.required) ? 'ng-required="true" ' : '';`

2) Replace these two lines:

```
var el = $compile(template)(scope);
element.replaceWith(template);
```

with

```
element.append(template);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

You can use `replace: true` in the directive definition to remove the `<input-field />` element. I struggled with this issue for ages and eventually found an example that worked for me on SO but I can't find that question right now. If I do I will update my answer.

I have created a new working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mb587k27MKcPShhkmAjA?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

input is marked as invalid by `red` border this style is added as `.has-error .form-control` and here `.has-error` class is added using `ng-class` *`(ng-class="{'has-error':innerForm.userInput.$invalid}")`*

The `inputField` directive is a `isolated scoped` *(because marked as isolated by `scope: {}`)* directive and this directive's scope is a child scope. and this child scope cant see parent scope properties other than specified items in `scope: {}` in here `inputField` directive can only access to `item: '=item'` item attribute value. **And parent scope cant see anything inside the child scope.**

Here the input is in directive scope. `input` fields are `compiled` against directive scope so that parent scope which `<ng-form class="user-form" name="innerForm"><div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error':innerForm.userInput.$invalid}">..` is lies in, cant see the `input` properties. so that the error class `has-error` can not be apply to the input because this input and the directive is not related they are in different scopes.

You can move the `<ng-form class="user-form" name="innerForm">..` in to the directive and it will work, because all are in the same scope here.

in html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input-field item="item"></input-field>
</div>
```

directive

```
var form_start = "<ng-form class='user-form' name='innerForm'><div class='form-group has-feedback' ng-class=\"{'has-error':innerForm.userInput.$invalid}\"><label class='control-label'>{[{ item.item }]}</label>";

    SWITCH STATEMENT

var form_end = "</div></ng-form>";

template = form_start+template+form_end;
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8kHB56RMc3V8bjQqneTT?p=preview)